# Read Comma Delimited String line by line for valye

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code which takes a file's encrypted contents and decrypts it into a string. This is simply just a comma Delimited string like the following:

Garry, 001, 0006

Ben, 002, 00

I want to check the values in column 0 and 1 match the contents of a textbox, but It has to be on the same row hence why I need to read each row/line. I've got most of it to work, I just dont know how to read the string line by line and check it's columns, could someone help?

My commented code is just pseudo code for what I'm trying to do.

```
Using TextReader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Garry\Desktop\test.txt")
    Dim EncryptedString As String = TextReader.ReadToEnd
    Dim DecryptedString As String = AESD(EncryptedString, Password)

    Dim strReader As New StringReader(DecryptedString)

    Dim line As String = strReader.ReadLine

    'If Line.column(0).contains(txtName.text) AND Line.column(1).contains(txtEnteredKey.text) then 

    'Else
    'Go to next line
    'End If

End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by the `,` and then compare the columns to your desired value.  For example, if I wanted to find `Ben` in the list, I could do this:

```
Dim s As String = "Garry, 001, 0006
Ben, 002, 00"

Dim strReader As New StringReader(s)

Dim line = strReader.ReadLine
While String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) = False
    Dim parts = line.Split(","c)
    If (parts(0).Trim() = "Ben" And parts(1).Trim() = "002") Then
        Console.WriteLine("Found ben!")
        Exit While
    End If
    line = strReader.ReadLine
End While
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thank you, I slightly adapted this to fit my needs. I'm extremely grateful john.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
    Dim DecryptedString As String = AESD(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Garry\Desktop\test.txt"), Password)

    Dim values() As String
    For Each line As String In DecryptedString.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        values = line.Split(",")
        If values.Length >= 2 AndAlso values(0) = txtName.Text AndAlso values(1) = txtEnteredKey.Text Then
            ' ... do something ...
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```